# Algorithms All construct in Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, recursion, 2d

I'm Stuck in this algorithm, the output is not what i expected, the goal is to retrieve all the possible ways inside of an array in to a 2D array concatenating the possible multiple solution to recreate the given target.

**Expected Output**

```
[
["purp", "le"]
["p","ur", "p", "le"]
]
```

**OutPut**
[]

```
def all_contruct(target, wordBank)
  return [[]] if target == ''
  result = []

  wordBank.each do |word|
    if target.index(word) == 0
      suffix = target.slice(word.length)

    suffixResult = all_contruct(suffix, wordBank)
    suffixWay  = suffixResult.map { |e| [ word, *e]  }

    result.push(*suffixWay)
    end
  end
  return result
end



all_contruct("purple",["purp","p","ur","le","purpl"])
#=> []
```

Comment: What is your expected outcome?

Comment: this is the expected output: [
["purp", "le"]
["p","ur", "p", "le"]
]

Comment: You need to first explain what you are trying to do, without reference to your code. In doing that it would be helpful to include a small example. Examples must include the input data, shown as one or more Ruby objects and the expected return value, also a Ruby object. It's helpful to assign a variable to each input (e.g. `arr = [1,2,..]`). That way readers can refer to those variables (`arr`) in answers and comments.

Comment: Your last line give an example but you need to move that to precede your code, explain the significance of each of the method's two arguments (the second being an array of strings) and--importantly--show the desired return value for those two arguments.

Comment: Thanks  @CarySwoveland for your suggestion i will stick toi it  for sure hopefully  somebody  already  helped  me out and the answer  is down bellow if anyone  else have the same issue.

Comment: Here's a simple, but relatively time-inefficient (but space-efficient) solution: `word = "purple"; arr = ["purp", "p", "ur", "le", "purpl"]; (1..arr.size).each_with_object([]) { |n,ar| arr.repeated_permutation(n) { |a| ar << a if a.join == word } } #=> [["purp", "le"], ["p", "ur", "p", "le"]]`. See [Array#repeated_permutation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-repeated_permutation).

Comment: Better to use recursion, however, as @Fravadona has done. The recursive method can alternatively be written as follows: `def doit(word, arr, root = []); arr.each_with_object([]) do |w,a|; new_root = root + [w]; new_word = new_root.join; if new_word == word; a << new_root; elsif word.start_with?(new_word); doit(word, arr, new_root).each { |e a << e }; end; end; end`. Then `doit("purple", ["purp", "p", "ur", "le", "purpl"]) #=> [["purp", "le"], ["p", "ur", "p", "le"]]`.

Comment: The recursion could be made much more efficient by first computing `h = arr.repeated_permutation(2).with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) { |(f,t),h| h[f] << t if word.include?([f,t].join) } #=> {"purp"=>["le"], "p"=>["ur", "le"], "ur"=>["p"]}`. This tells us that if `"purp"` is used as part of the word it can only be followed by `"le"`, if `"p"` is used as part of the word it can only be followed by `"ur"` or `"le"` and if `"ur"` is used as part of the word it can only be followed by `"p"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

```rb
def all_contruct target, wordBank
  possibleWords = wordBank.select{|word| target.start_with? word}
  possibleWords.each_with_object([]) do |word,result|
    rest = target.delete_prefix word
    if rest.empty?
      result << [word]
    else
      send(__method__,rest,wordBank).each {|tail| result << [word] + tail}
    end
  end
end

all_contruct("purple",["purp","p","ur","le","purpl"])
#=> [["purp", "le"], ["p", "ur", "p", "le"]]
```

**Update**: unexpectedly, it turned out to be a one-liner

```rb
def all_contruct target, wordBank
  wordBank.select{|w| target.start_with? w}.each_with_object([]) { |w,r| (t = target.delete_prefix w).empty? ? r << [w] : send(__method__,t,wordBank).each {|c| r << [w] + c} }
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. @fravadona

Comment: You're welcome ;-) Does it work as expected ?

Comment: Yes Perfectly, i will probably optimize it with Memoization.